# Applying a function to a list of elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Say i've defined a Queue and have the following function:

```
pushq :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a

pushq x (Queue1 xs) = Queue1 (x:xs)
```

It works by adding a single element it to the front of a queue, but say I wanted to use the function in another method which would add an entire list of elements to a queue rather than a single one such as:

```
adds :: [a] -> Queue a -> Queue a
```

How would I be able iterate through the list and use the pushq function on every element one by one to add it to the queue?

Comment: Hint: use recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I be able iterate through the list and use the pushq function on every element one by one to add it to the queue?

Through recursion. For an empty list you can return the `Queue a` itself:

```
adds [] qs = qs
```

for a non-empty list, you first call `adds` on the tail of the list, and then push that element on the queue:

```
adds (x:xs) q = pushq … (adds …)
```

you still have to fill in the `…`s here. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: This is what I was able to come up with correct me if i'm wrong: adds (x:xs) q = addq x(adds xs q)

Comment: @subprimeloads: yes, that is correct. Although it is probably `pushq` instead of `addq`.

Comment: This is very nearly the ideal place for `foldr`, as in `adds = foldr pushq` (with the arguments reversed) or `adds xs q = foldr pushq q xs` (if you must have the arguments in that order).

Comment: @DanielWagner: I was indeed tempted to do this, but I guess that this might not be the level that the OP is currently capable of (no offense).

Comment: Agreed. But I leave my comment in case it is helpful to some future reader at a different skill level.